# Will my "6-core CPU" motherboard support an 8-core CPU?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

My motherboard is an [ECS A885GM-A2 (V1.1)](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=1120&CategoryID=1&MenuID=19&LanID=0).  I recently decided to buy [a new 8-core CPU](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819113285).  I only checked the socket-type and the wattage; I've never heard of "number of cores" being an issue.

However, when I opened the case, I saw my motherboard says

> 6-core CPU support

I don't know if this is a reassurance that *"this motherboard supports 6-core CPUs"* or a warning that *"This motherboard **only** supports up to 6-core CPUs"*.

I'd rather not waste several hours and a bottle of thermal paste just to find out it doesn't work.  So, if I put this CPU into my motherboard, **will it work at all?** If it does, **will I be able to use all 8-cores?**

Comment: What CPU are you trying to upgrade from exactly?

Comment: Of course all the supported CPUs supported by that motherboard is also simply listed [here](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=1120&CategoryID=1&MenuID=19&LanID=0#fragment-CPU)

Comment: @Ramhound my *old* CPU is a Phenom II x4 955

Comment: All you had to do was look at the list of supported CPUs for your motherboard. You were already at ECS' website for your motherboard. I have down-voted the question for *not showing research effort*.

Answer (score 7):

Your original CPU a `Phenom II X4 955` is a **AM3** socket product.  That is the reason it worked with your AM3 motherboard.  The `AMD FX-8320` is an AM3+ socket product which is not supported by this specific motherboard.

The motherboard's specifications indicate the following:

- Support **AM3** socket for AMD Phenom™ II processors
- High-performance HyperTransport 3.0 CPU Interface
- Support transfer rate up to 5200 mega-transfers per second

The `AMD FX-8320` is not supported by the `ECS A885GM-A2` motherboard you have.

If you want a 6-core processor then the following are supported by your motherboard:

1. `AMD Phenom II X6 Six-Core 1045T`
2. `AMD Phenom II X6 Six-Core 1035T`
3. `AMD Phenom II X6 Six-Core 1055T`
4. `AMD Phenom II X6 Six-Core 1065T`
5. `AMD Phenom II X6 Six-Core 1075T`
6. `AMD Phenom II X6 Six-Core 1090T (BE)`
7. `AMD Phenom II X6 Six-Core 1100T (BE)`

[Complete List of Supported AM3 CPUs](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=1120&CategoryID=1&MenuID=19&LanID=0#fragment-CPU)

Comment: Er, I thought the whole point of the AM3+ socket-type was that it was backwards compatible with AM3 sockets, but also forward-compatible with the upcoming AM4 socket?  At least, that's how it worked with AM2/AM2+..  But in either case, while this does solve my problem, it does not answer the question in the title, for anyone who finds this page via google, so I cannot mark it as correct.

Comment: @BlueRaja - The motherboard has to support it.  Its not a guaranteed backwards support.  How does this not answer the question?

Comment: @BlueRaja - Since you wanted to know specifically about 6-core professors I have copied the information from the technical specifications and listed the supported 6-core processors.

Comment: As someone from the Intel crowd who doesn't follow AMD sockets, your answer isn't entirely clear. Are you saying the OP had an AM3 Cpu in an AM2 mobo (the `ECS A885GM-A2`) and that the new AM3+ Cpu won't work in the old motherboard? Also, I don't believe OP wanted 6-core unless you're saying that's the only option? It would be helpful if as well as quoting facts, you could include a sentence or two to answer the question as asked.

Comment: @Basic - The `A885GM-A2` is a AM3 motherboard.  I have provided specifications of the motherboard itself it does not indicate it supports AMD3+ products, it specifically indicates it supports AM3 products, there isn't anything else to say.  I linked to the complete list of supported CPUs for reason.

Comment: @BlueRaja: How does "The AMD FX-8320 is an AM3+ socket product which is not supported by this specific motherboard." not answer the question "Will my ... motherboard support an 8-core CPU (specifially, an FX-8320)?" ?

Comment: Read the entire answer I literally say it won't...

Answer (score 1):

Number of cores is not the issue in your case with your motherboard. It is the actual pin configuration of the board and the AM3+ CPU.

While AM3s have 941 pins the AM3+ has 942.

What seems to be the quick tell tail sign if a motherboard is AM3+ compatible is a white block vs Black block. What you really need to do is look at the red circled area for the extra pin hole or lack there of.

Some manufactures had AM3+ ready boards that had the 942 pin block and would later update the BIOS to use these newer processors. This allowed for later compatibility with that motherboard and I believe there was something like "AM3+ ready" in the motherboards description or tech specs at that time.

That being said, the AM3+ FX series started the eight core AMD line. Some motherboard makers made "FX" versions for use of the upcoming (at that time) processors.

To your title question: Will YOUR 6 core CPU mother board support an 8-core CPU? No.

While AM3 CPUs can have backwards compatibility with AM3+ boards (Check the makers supporting CPU list and BIOS, wattage requirements), an AM3+ CPU will not fit into a AM3 Only motherboard.

[image: CPU]

Comment: In this case, the socket was the issue rather than the number of cores because the chip wouldn't physically fit.  Does that mean that there is nothing inherently incompatible with an 8 core CPU as long as it fits the socket?  Or does the socket define that the motherboard is capable of fully using any CPU that will fit (so a 6 core CPU with 940 pins would work in an AM3+ socket)?  Or is it a case of reading the mobo specs to see if a particular CPU will work?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: motherboard only supports AM3 CPUs, and FX series uses AM3+. The difference is in 1 pin (940 and 941 are correct numbers as far as I remember). AM3 motherboards don't support AM3+ processors, but reverse is generally true (I have motherboard with AM3+ socket running AM3 CPU).

Nothing to do with number of cores, they just aren't compatible.